# Address Resolution on WiFi with TP-LINK router

Tags: router, home-networking, ping, arp

I have a TP-LINK WiFi router which shows lan IP addresses and computer mac addresses under **Device Info > ARP**. I am interested to read this info from my computer (Ubuntu 12.04) connected to the same network. Is there an Ubuntu command for it which can query IP/MAC list from router and show in terminal?

If there isn't any command. Is there a hit and test mechanism which I can use to collect lan IP addresses? What I would do is select IP address range **192.168.1.2** to **192.168.1.255** and ping it and see who replies. This will be very specific because I know all IP addresses on my networks are of class C. Do you know anything better than Ping?

Answer (score 1):

The program nmap does exactly that, by scouting your network without polling your router. You can install it with (Debian & friends first, then Arch,...)

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
sudo pacman -S nmap
```

and then you can poll your network with

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

But be advised, nmap is a very powerful program with many options, allowing an enormous body of information to be collected from the other nodes, not just their IP/MAC addresses.

Comment: isn't there something built into Ubuntu itself? Can I find source code of nmap?

Comment: Depends on what you mean. There is nothing built into Ubuntu of this power, but there are several programs monitoring ARP traffic, like arp-scan. The source code for nmap is available at [link](http://nmap.org/download.html)